# How to write xpath rule in pmd to identify deprecated api of third party jars

Tags: xpath, pmd, xpath-2.0

In my project I am using third party jars.
   With the latest release of jars, few methods are 
   deprecated in the class. For example.

V1.0

```
Class Base{
    Public void Foo(){};
};
```

V2.0

```
Class Base{
    Public void Foo(){}; //deprecated
    Public void foo1(){};//use this in newer version
};
```

I want to write the custom xpath rule for pdm to identify Foo() usage, so that it should give high priority issue.

My Application Code

```
public class myMain()
{
  public void Foo(){};
  public int main()
  {
    Base b = new Base();
    b.Foo(); // pmd should give high priority issue
    Foo(); // pmd should not give issue here.
  }
}
```

Comment: What language is this? If it's Java then you should use the `@Deprecated` annotation and let the compiler emit warnings itself. It looks like the code has many syntax errors though.

Comment: its not java, its xpath rule

Comment: I'm asking about the language you're analysing, the one of your code snippets. It looks like Java with syntax errors.